# How to set date in gridview update

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

i have this issue.
VB code using Web Developer Express 2010

Using datasource from access.
I cant select and update... from one gridview (call GW)
I need to set always the date when the user update the info. how u do that?
I trie several idea. By all null value in the gridview column date, set to current system date.. dont work 4 me.
Then true the update process same problem using the `DefaultValue="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>"`

Any idea please? Thanks in advance.. BR

```
`UpdateCommand="UPDATE [partes] SET [ESTATU] = ?,[SCONF] = ?, [SNOTES] = ?, [CONFDAT] = ?, [DCREA] = ?, [ASN] = ?, [ASNDATE] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">

        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ESTATU" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SCONF" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SNOTES" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CONFDAT" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DCREA" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ASN" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ASNDATE" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>`
```

THIS IS THE ERROR
Server Error in '/' Application.

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is your Culture Info. Your DateTime.ToString() may return MM/DD/YYYY when your application expects DD/MM/YYYY. I have encountered this several time. 
For example

```
Your application expects 29/05/2012 and
DateTime.Now() returns 05/29/2012 making Month=29 which is invalid
```

That is one of the scenario I faced

Comment: well today is 5/29/2012  i run a test in the label and the system return in the same format  mm/dd/yyyy. i do the othe test in the asp parameters:  <asp:Parameter Name="DCREA" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="12/29/2012" />  and is ok then "29/12/2012" same error like with the <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" ...  now i fix this? I change in the columns date format string to {0:MM-dd-yyyy} .. and keep the problem.. other idea?

Comment: Use ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), this should be understood properly by application and database

Comment: nop... this error in the datacontrol: is not allowed within a System.web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of setting the date value in the `_Updating` (or `_Inserting` if needed) event for the ObjectDataSource or related datasource control you are using as opposed to the source. A code sample is below, but obviously, you need to generate this event for *your* control:

```
Private Sub ObjectDataSource1_Updating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs) Handles ObjectDataSource1.Updating

  'Set Update parameters programmatically before calling wired up Update method:
  e.InputParameters.Item("DCREA") = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString)

End Sub
```

You can call any of the 'ToShort/Long' etc. methods on the `DateTime.Now` object that is appropriate for your needs. You could also just simply call `Now.ToString()` as you have done as well. Just providing some options based on the detail you need.

Comment: Dont work.... i get this error "Error 1 Method 'Private Sub data1_Updating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs)' cannot handle event 'Public Event Updating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)' because they do not have a compatible signature. C:\Users\Luis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BUYERS\BUYERS\WebForm3.aspx.vb 7 140 BUYERS"

Comment: Did you try and create this method manually or let the IDE auto generate it for you? Sounds like the signature is not correct. The 'Handles' statement may not be wired to the proper ODS control. Use the dropdowns above the code to select the 'Updated' event from your ODS to make sure it gets created properly in the code.

Answer (score 0):

u have two need just two things on gridview apply event onupdated row i don't which event supporting vb but i can tell u in asp.net u can do this like

apply event on gridView Like:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_Updating"></asp:GridView>

UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Organizations] SET [ModifyDate] = @ModifyDate

<UpdateParameters>

          <asp:Parameter Name="ModifyDate" Type="DateTime" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>


protected void GridView1_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValues["ModifyDate"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

I hope this pieace of code will help you.